# Javascript Calendar deselecting date when date is selected again instead of reselecting it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, calendar

I use a calendar from No Gray, found at http://www.nogray.com/calendar.php, and I have realised that the problems I have been having is due to when you click on the same date that has already been selected, it deselects the date instead of reselecting it again and if it is passed through in a form, the value for that field is empty.

I have read up on the use of the software and the options and the only option I can see that may help is the "ng.Calendar.is_selected" found at http://www.nogray.com/api/calendar/is_selected.php, and I am not sure if that is correct, but even on their demo on their own website, it works the same way and deselects the date instead of reselecting it.

I have tried everything but can't get it to perform where if you click the same date that is already selected, it does not deselect the date and just reselects it.

The example is here http://www.nogray.com/example.php?ID=260.

How can this been done please as I have tried now for a week with no joy.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi R A, the unselect the date is a standard setup for the calendar. How do you want the "reselect a date" functionality to work.

Comment: I want it so that when you have already selected a date, if you go back after that calendar has closed and select that date again, it doesn't unselect it and will always have a date value to use in form, as a date is always required and currently when you do that, it unselects the date and leaves the input field empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example might help, but the user won't be able to unselect a date unless they clear the input field.

```
<input id="forced_click_select" type="text">
<script src="PATH/TO/ng_all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="PATH/TO/components/calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ng.ready( function() {
    var fcs_cal = new ng.Calendar({
        input: 'forced_click_select',
        events: {
            onDateClick: function(dt){
                this.select_date(dt);
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

http://www.nogray.com/example.php?ID=307

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. I want it so that when you have already selected a date, if you go back after that calendar has closed and select that date again, it doesn't unselect it and will always have a date value to use in form, as a date is always required and currently when you do that, it unselects the date and leaves the input field empty. Currently I have       input: {date:'date1', month:'month1', year:'year1'},selected_date:new Date(),display_date:new Date(),dates_off:[{date:1, month:0},{date:25, month:11}], then a onSelect event. Thanks

Comment: Hi R A, the code above will keep the date selected after the user click it, but if the user clears the input field the date will be unselected. You probably need a simple validation before processing the form. For example (using the code above), `if (!ng.defined(fcs_cal.get_last_selected_date())) alert("Please select a date");`

Comment: If you want a custom version of the calendar that does not unselect the, please contact us at http://www.nogray.com/contact.php and we'll send you the update file by email.

Comment: Thanks. The code you stated above, if (!ng.defined(fcs_cal.get_last_selected_date())) alert("Please select a date"); Does that go in the <HEAD> area as a script or in the ng.ready area?

Comment: I have tried using it with my other validation in the <HEAD> and I have tried using it in the events area also but neither work.

Comment: Currently I am using date1, month1, year1, date2, month2 and year2 as selects but creating it as an input so it outputs the seperate field values for each, so there are 2 calendars and then I have created it with onSelect for each calendar with some custom code I wrote to calculate the difference in days with outputs.

Comment: It'll depend on where the calendars are defined. Please contact us directly with a sample of your code or a URL and we can send you details on where to add the validation method

Comment: Just fixed it all. Was missing a comma after the events for each calendar. Always a silly mistake! Thank you for your help. Great response. ;)

Comment: Thank you @NoGray for your help. I have another question relating to the NoGray Calendar which I have posted here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898866/javascript-nogray-calendar-find-next-available-date. If you have the time to answer it, it would be much appreciated and would be helpful to show others looking for a similar solution with your software. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you again @NoGray, but I have posted a follow-up question to this answer as even though the answer is correct for standalone use, if used with blocked dates, it doesn't seem to work. The new posted question relating to this is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046337/javascript-nogray-calendar-not-working-with-blocked-dates-using-this-is-selectab. I'd appreciate if you would help and explain why this doesn't work with blocked dates using the above approach. Thanks.