# Javascript NoGray Calendar find next available date after chosen blocked dates if today is blocked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

I am using the `NoGray Calendar` and have the following code:

```
my_cal1 = new ng.Calendar({
    input: {date:'date1', month:'month1', year:'year1'},
    selected_date:new Date(),display_date:new Date(),
    dates_off:[{date:22, month:6},
    events: {
        onDateClick: function(dt) {
            this.select_date(dt);
        }
    }
```

But when it is the same day as the day I am on, it shows as blank.

How can I make it so it displays and looks for the next available date to start from after the blocked date please?

The example calendar can be found here at http://www.nogray.com/example.php?ID=260

The areas that I am trying to set are the `start_date` and `display_date` to the next available date so if I had the next 3 days as days off, it would show the date as the next available date after those 3 days when it starts.

Can this be done with the functions within the NoGray software or do I require to use a PHP script to search for the next available date and out put the required date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `is_selectable` http://www.nogray.com/api/calendar/is_selectable.php to check if the dates are selectable or not. The `is_selectable` returns an array [true|false, 'reason']. Below is a quick example

```
my_cal1 = new ng.Calendar({
    input: {date:'date1', month:'month1', year:'year1'},
    selected_date:new Date(),
    display_date:new Date(),
    dates_off:[{date:22, month:6}], // you were messing a ] here
    events: {
        onDateClick: function(dt){
            this.select_date(dt);
        },
        // code to check if the start date is selectable
        onLoad: function(){
            var st_dt = this.get_start_date().clone();
            while(!this.is_selectable(st_dt)[0]){
                st_dt = st_dt.from_string('today + 1');
            }
            // checking if no dates are selected
            if (!ng.defined(this.get_selected_date())){
                this.select_date(st_dt);
            }
            this.set_start_date(st_dt);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried and tested this with the 22,23,24,25 and 26 with month as 6, for July, as dates_off and it still doesn't jump to the next available dates. How can this be done please? Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: Make sure you have a correct array for the dates of (note the comments in the code). Here is a live example http://www.nogray.com/calendar_test.php

Comment: Thank you @NoGray. That's perfect. Also, for a second calendar to read the first selected date, add 7 days (+7) and check that date is not blocked and if so go to the next available day, where would I add the +7 and check the next available date if blocked? Normally, I would have var myDate=new Date(); myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7); but that won't work if the start date on the other calendar is not available today and has been moved to the next available date. How would this be done? Thanks again.

Comment: You can review the range calendar example here http://www.nogray.com/example.php?ID=286

Which has everything you need to build a range calendar.

Comment: Thank you once again but I was unable to find an answer in the example from what I can tell. I have posted another question to show this problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956486/javascript-nogray-calendar-add-number-of-days-to-date-check-availability-after. I do hope you can help as having it on here in StackOverflow will help anyone who maybe looking for the same help. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I was able to answer the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956486/javascript-nogray-calendar-add-number-of-days-to-date-check-availability-after but I now have a problem turning the input field to drop down boxes found. I have asked the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962734/javascript-nogray-calendar-use-drop-down-boxes-with-calendar-instead-of-input-fi. @NoGray , would you know how to do this?